# Python different errors when executing in PyCharm and in shell

Tags: python, linux, shell, pycharm, ide

I've worked on my python project in PyCharm. When I'm executing its different files everything goes smoothly. However, when I'm executing the files in shell, it seems like I get errors that I don't get in the IDE.

For example, being a simplified structure of my project:

```
+--PROJECT
   +--data
      +--myfile.csv
   +--__init__.py
   +--main.py
```

And being a simplified main.py:

```
import pandas as pd

if __name__ == "__main__":
   dataframe = pd.read_csv("data/myfile.csv", on_bad_lines='skip', sep=sep)
```

The execution in PyCharm is clean, while when I run it in Shell it yields:

```
TypeError: parser_f() got an unexpected keyword argument 'on_bad_lines'
```

I guess this could be a matter of  Python versions, but I don't quite see where the problem is. I have a 3.8 version in  PyCharm and a 3.8.10 in  Linux.

EDITED: Included the source file and its path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What version of pandas do you use? According to [this documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) the `on_bad_lines` is only added in 1.3.0. You can check that by using

```py
$ python  # start an interpreter
>>> import pandas
>>> print(pandas.__version__)
```

Comment: Indeed, the interpreter's pandas version is 1.0.4 and Pycharm uses 1.3.5